# Is CloudFront (backed by S3) a good way to serve user-uploaded pictures?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Is CloudFront (backed by S3) a good way to serve user-uploaded pictures? For example forum avatars. Or maybe there is a better way?

Comment: What are your needs?  What would distinguish between a *good* way and a *bad* way (Cost, scalability, difficulty, resilience, capacity etc.)?  What have you tried and why isn't that good enough?

Comment: @Ladadadada The main criteria is performance (latency). Uploaded image will be served at least thousands times a day. Also the images should be immediately available after upload. Also system needs to have reasonable costs and complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudfront/s3 is a good solution if performance matters and the images will have 1000+ hits/day.
The complexity and costs are also reasonable in my experience. 
You also have a Read-after-Write Consistency for s3 if you create new objects. You dont have that consistency for updated objects, though.